# How can I implement a predicate which converts a propositional formula to a normal form?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to implement an `unfold` predicate which takes a propositional formula and returns one where the only logical operators are conjunction, disjunction and negation.

**Code**:

```
:- op(1060, yfx, <->). 
:- op(1050, yfx, <-). 
:- op(800, yfx, xor).
:- op(600, yfx, v).  
:- op(400, yfx, &). 
:- op(200, fy, ¬). 

define((F xor G),  ¬ (F <-> G)).
define((F <-> G), (F -> G) & (F <- G)). 
define((F <- G), (G -> F)).
define((F -> G), ¬ F v G).

% Base case: atomic formula
unfold(A, A) :- atom(A).
unfold(¬ A, NA) :- unfold(A, UA), define(UA, NA1), NA = ¬ NA1.
unfold(A & B, C) :- unfold(A, UA), unfold(B, UB), define(UA, C1), define(UB, C2), C = C1 & C2.
unfold(A v B, C) :- unfold(A, UA), unfold(B, UB), define(UA, C1), define(UB, C2), C = C1 v C2.
unfold(A xor B, C) :- unfold(A, UA), unfold(B, UB), define((UA xor UB), C).
unfold(A <-> B, C) :- unfold(A, UA), unfold(B, UB), define((UA <-> UB), C).
unfold(A <- B, C) :- unfold(A, UA), unfold(B, UB), define((UA <- UB), C).
unfold(A -> B, C) :- unfold(A, UA), unfold(B, UB), define((UA -> UB), C).
```

However, that doesn't work. At first I missed the base case, then I added it but I only get `false`. For example, this query should return:

```
-? unfold( p <-> q & ¬ r, G ).
G= ( ¬p v ¬q & ¬r) & ( ¬ (q & ¬ r) v p).
```

Thank you for any guidance or help.

Comment: See https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/logic for some ideas (and do note the bibliographic reference).

Comment: Thank you, @Paulo Moura. And the bibliographic reference is also nice. Could you tell me why do you have the fact `distribute_negation(P, P).` in your prolog file ?

Comment: That's what's called a *catchall* clauses that's used when none of the previous clauses apply. Note that the code was adapted from the Clocksin & Mellish book.

Comment: [Crossposting](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/how-can-i-implement-unfold-predicate/6477).

Comment: @false, isn't crossposting referred to posting between different SE sites or just anywhere in the internet ? Are you just citing that so people has multiple options to look at a similar problem ? By the way, I learn so much for your through and deep prolog explanations.

Answer (score 2):

When I run your program, it fails when trying `unfold(~r, NA)`, because it fails on `define(r, NA1)`. It seems that define for an atom hasn't been written. I use SWI-PROLOG and am using gtrace for debugging; that's how I found the fault.

Solution: write define/2 to handle atoms. There may of course be other missing clauses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I didn't get the notification in my mail. I will test as soon as I can.

Comment: Sorry for my really late response. I added `define(A, A)` and now I get: `G = (p<->q& ¬r)` when I run the query `unfold( p <-> q & ¬ r, G ).`. Is that what you mean by write define/2 to handle atoms ?